# LINQ: Group by Date Range within 5 minutes

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Let's say I have the following collection of items and Dates:

```
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:30 AM
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:32 AM
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:33 AM
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:34 AM
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:57 AM

ItemID: 2, Date: 10/10/2018 7:45 AM
ItemID: 2, Date: 10/10/2018 7:49 AM

ItemID: 3, Date: 10/10/2018 8:45 AM
ItemID: 3, Date: 10/10/2018 9:13 AM
```

I'd like to group by ItemID and Date but the dates I want them group by the ones that fall within 5 minutes of each other

In the data set above the following would be grouped

```
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:30 AM    <-- Grouped with Item 1
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:32 AM    <-- Grouped with Item 1
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:33 AM    <-- Grouped with Item 1
ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:34 AM    <-- Grouped with Item 1


ItemID: 1, Date: 10/10/2018 11:57 AM    <-- Not Grouped


ItemID: 2, Date: 10/10/2018 7:45 AM    <-- Grouped with Item 2
ItemID: 2, Date: 10/10/2018 7:49 AM    <-- Grouped with Item 2


ItemID: 3, Date: 10/10/2018 8:45 AM    <-- Not Grouped

ItemID: 3, Date: 10/10/2018 9:13 AM    <-- Not Grouped
```

The ones that are grouped are the ones that fall within 5 minutes of each other.

I know how to group them by ItemID and Date in LINQ but I'm having a hard time grouping them the way I described.

What I've tried so far:

```
var groupedItems = from item in items
              group item by new
              {
                  item.ItemID,
                  item.Date
              } into g
              select g;
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried?

Comment: @GiladGreen Updated. Sorry I'm new to LINQ I'm just learning it.

Comment: Is this an in memory collection or does it execute in the database?

Comment: @GiladGreen In-memory collection

Comment: what output you needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var groupedItems = items
    .GroupBy(i => i.ItemId, (k, g) => g
        .GroupBy(i => (long)new TimeSpan(i.Date.Ticks - g.Min(e => e.Date).Ticks).TotalMinutes / 5))
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: I tried it with these times: 11:12, 11:13, 11:14 and 11:15, it grouped (11:12, 11:13, 11:14) together but it did not group 11:15. The IntervalKey for the first group was 212249366, the IntervalKey for 11:15 item that was not grouped is 212249367

Comment: @EricBergman What are the bounds then? 11:10 to 11:15 or 11:12 to 11:17?

Comment: Example if we have: 11:12, 11:13, 11:14, 11:15, 11:30, 11:35 it should group the ones that fall within 5 minutes of each other, in this case we should have two groups (11:12, 11:13, 11:14, 11:15) and (11:30, 11:35), it would be safe to assume that there will only be up to 4 items that fall within the 5 minute range within a specific hour but no more

Comment: @EricBergman I've updated my answer. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you so much arekzyla

Answer (score 2):

My attempt at your solution:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>{ ... }; // dates get initialized however your code does it...

var groups = dates.Select(d => 
    d, 
    GroupDate = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, (d.Minute / 5) * 5, d.Second)})
    .GroupBy(g => g.GroupDate);
```

The math for the Minute is going to, ultimately, separate by which whole multiple of 5 the minute falls into.  Another caveat is that if you don't care about day/month/year and want to group everything explicitly by minute, then scratch the `new DateTime(...)` piece and replace with `(d.Minute / 5) * 5`.  That will group by minute regardless of day/month/year.

Hope this helps!