# C# Group a date range in parts according to a specific number of days

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a list on Dates:

```
2021/09/01
2021/09/02
2021/09/03
2021/09/04
2021/09/05
2021/09/06
2021/09/07
2021/09/08
2021/09/09
......

2021/09/29
```

How to group date range in 7-day chunks?:

```
2021/09/01
2021/09/02
2021/09/03
2021/09/04
2021/09/05
2021/09/06
2021/09/07

2021/09/08
2021/09/09
2021/09/10
2021/09/11
2021/09/12
2021/09/13
2021/09/14

....
```

Comment: can you post any initial attempts?

Comment: might [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52747848/5174469) help you?

Comment: Will there be gaps in the list of dates?

Comment: @Markus Yes, there will be an gaps in the list

Comment: how do you want to treat the transition between the months?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data that might contain gaps or several entries for a date, you can calculate the difference to the minimum date and use it for grouping, e.g.:

```
if (dates.Any()) // Min() will fail if there are no dates
{
  var minDate = dates.Min(x => x);
  var interval = 7d;
  var groups = from x in dates 
               group x by x.Subtract(minDate).TotalDays / interval 
               into g 
               select g;
}
```

The above sample can be used as a guideline; you might need to adjust it to your data structures and requirements.